# R data.frame modify some values of a column depending on a factorial column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R looking like this:

```
 ...    vals         cat  ...
        1.2          TRUE
        1.6          FALSE
        5            TRUE
```

I like to modify the values in the "vals" column depending on if the factor in the cat 
column is TRUE or false. Lets say I want to multiply the value in the vals column 
with a factor (e.g 9) when the category of the same row says TRUE.

As result I would like to 
have a copy of the original dataframe but with the modified values instead. Or a dataframe with one more column containing the original values if unmodified (FALSE) and the modified if cat 
was TRUE.

Hope somebody could 
give me a hand with this.

Best Regards Sab.

Comment: `vals2 <- vals; vals2[cat] <- vals2 * 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- data.frame(vals=c(11.2,9.1,2.1),cat=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))

x
  vals   cat
1 11.2  TRUE
2  9.1 FALSE
3  2.1  TRUE

y <- x

y[y$cat,] <- x[x$cat,]*9

y
   vals cat
1 100.8   9
2   9.1   0
3  18.9   9
```

Comment: I'll just point out that, if the original values aren't needed, you can replace `x$vals` by itself... and that you don't need the `[,]` there.  `x$vals[x$cat] <- x$vals[x$cat]*9`

Comment: For keeping cat values, you need to specify the vals column :`y[y$cat,1] <- x[x$cat,1]*9`